# Observe read only variable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Can I observe read only variable by RxSwift ?

I'm trying observe variable from extendal library ([iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel))

This is my code:

```
carouselView.rx.observe(Bool.self, "isScrolling")
    .map { $0 != nil }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (isScrolling) in
        print("isScrolling", isScrolling)
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Console print this but only one time:

```
isScrolling, false
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be because it is a User scrolling and not a programatic scrolling?

this is from iCarousel documentation.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isScrolling) BOOL scrolling;
```

Returns YES if the carousel is currently being scrolled programatically.

if that is the case you might want to use these in a combination

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isDragging) BOOL dragging;
```

Returns YES if user has started scrolling the carousel and has not yet released it.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = isDecelerating) BOOL decelerating;
```

Returns YES if the user isn't dragging the carousel any more, but it is still moving.

Comment: Okey, but I'm scrolling programatically

Answer (score 0):

I see it now. This is equal to

```
.map { $0 != nil } 

.map{return ($0 != nil)}
```

so you are not return weather or not it is nil but the boolean value of it being nil.
what you want to use is filter

like

```
carouselView.rx.observe(Bool.self, "isScrolling")
    .filter { $0 != nil }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (isScrolling) in
        print("isScrolling", isScrolling)
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: are you still getting false values or do you just get one value?

Comment: Still One value ;(

Comment: maybe the value is not KVO compliant